# How to show Gridview after exporting to Excel in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I have wrote a program where the requirement is to when user select particular date then should show one report. And here the report I am showing is in Gridview in a separate page under button click even. But now it is required to download the report at the same time they click to view and store into some particular folder. So, I have written the below code and it is working to download the report into excel format into the particular folder but I cannot see the gridview anymore. I have put the below function into the pageload after binding data with the gridview but now I can see that while debuging the pointer coming to the binding grid and exporting excel again and again and the page shows error " The Web Page cannot be displayed." Please help me on this how may I fix this.

Here is my code example to write into excel and store into a location:

```
     private void ExportPagetoExl()
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cpIdStr))
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename="+ Request["year"] +"_" + Request["month"] + "_Transaction_" + requestChannel + ".xls");
    else
    {
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + Session["cpUsername"] + "_" + Request["year"] + "_" + Request["fullmonth"] + "_" + requestChannel + ".xls");
    }

    Response.Charset = string.Empty;
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    FileInfo FI = new FileInfo(@"C:\MyPC\Projects\report\transaction_" + requestChannel + "_" + Request["year"] + "_" + Request["fullmonth"] + ".xls");
    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    GridView1.DataSource = myData.DefaultView;
    GridView1.DataBind();


    try
    {
        GridViewRow header = GridView1.HeaderRow;
        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
        string style = "<style>.textmode{mso-number-format:\\@;}</style>";
        string directory = @"C:\MyPC\Projects\report\";
        if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
        }

        System.IO.StreamWriter vw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\MyPC\Projects\report\" + Request["year"] + "_" + Request["month"] + "_Transaction_" + requestChannel + ".xls", true);
        sw.ToString().Normalize();
        vw.Write(sw.ToString());
        vw.Flush();
        vw.Close();
        Response.Flush();
        Response.BufferOutput = true;
        Response.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have not specified the Datasource for GridView1. You first will have to specify DataSource and then do the GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: I have changed my code to bind with the datasource but still the same.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to do it together in current way, as when you are exporting the data to excel, you are playing with the response and returning only the file to the browser and nothing else.So your gridview, though you have binded, will be blank as the required html is not sent to the browser. Probably what you need to do is, first bind the gridview, and when your request goes back to browser, execute a javascript function that will go back again to the server and get the file for you, without user having to click any button.Hope what i say is clear.

Comment: To explain it better, When user clicks the button, On server side bind the gridview you wanna show.Probably by using "ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript", you can execute a javascript function which will use javascript __dopostback to go back to server and then you can execute the code to export the file.That way user only clicks one time, but you will force a second round trip to server to fetch excel file without user knowledge.If you don't want to use __dopostpack, you can have a hidden button and use jquery trigger() to click it dynamically.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you suggestion. Could you please provide me a sample of code as I am a bit unfamiliar to Javascript.

Comment: I have posted sample code as my answer, feel free to ask if you don't understand anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ASPX Code**

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ExportExcel() { //function to be executed from server side after gridview is bound
                $('#btnexport').click();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" Text="Submit" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="btnsubmit_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnexport" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" style="display:none;" OnClick="btnexport_Click" /><!--Hidden button  -->
                <asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Code Behind**

```
    protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Bind Gridview
        LoadGridview();
        //Call "ExportExcel();" Javascript function which has been defined in the aspx page 
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "com", "ExportExcel();", true);
    }

    protected void btnexport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //export the file here
        ExportToExcel();
    }
    private void LoadGridview()
    {
        //Your code to bind gridview goes here
    }
    private void ExportToExcel()
    {
        //Your code to export goes here
    }
```

**Explanation**

1. You have your main button "btnsubmit", on click of which, the gridview will be populated.
2. Create a hidden button "btnexport", set its style to display none so that it won't be visible to user. On its click event, write the code to export the excel.
3. On your aspx page define a function "ExportExcel(){}" which will dynamically call the click event of the hidden button.
4. When user clicks the "btnsubmit", on the server side, The code binds Gridview & executes "ExportExcel" using "ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript"
5. ExportExcel, inturn, executes the click event of "btnexport" which has the code to export the excel to browser.
6. Don't forget to have Jquery reference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the way of doing it.

- Create a page which has Gridview to show the data and add a control (either ActionLink or Button) to Export the data to excel beside it.
- Now use the default view to show the grid which is GridView1
- Put your code which is responsible to generate Excel in another method and call that method on button or ActionLink click.And use GridView2 for generating excel rather GridView1.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but my requirement is to export into excel without any button click so I am doing it on page load.

Comment: From your question it was not clear ! Answer remains same, Use another object of Gridview to show in webform rather the same as you have used to generate the excel.

Comment: I have added one more grid and trying to export excel from it but still I am having the same error. Everytime after executing the ExportPagetoExl function it goes back to the pageload again and again and after that it shows error: "This Webpage is not available"